# SWT JFACE: How to move one row to another row in JFace TableViewer by using TAB Key

Tags: tabs, row, jface, tableviewer

I have created a table viewer using JFace. Now i want to move from one row to another row by using TAB key, those rows are existed in TableViewer.

In my table viewer i have 5 rows with 2 columns, and one column is editable.
Now i want to move one row to another row by using TAB Key from keyboard.
As of now if i press TAB key, i can move to first row in the table viewer but i want to traverse every row in the table viewer by using TAB.

Comment: The answer in the duplicate question can be adapted to move to the next row easily.

Comment: From those 4 answers i can able to move from one column to other column. But i want to navigate in between the rows which are existed in swt table.

Comment: Just take the code from the accepted answer and set the selection to the next row.